# Drop down header issues

Tags: html, css

Hi i have 2 header as follow:

[image]

when i click the notification button, the drop down seems break the header layout. Following are the screenshot

[image]

The notification dropdown css are as follow

```
#notification_dropdown {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 13px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 13px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 0px 13px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
background: white;
border: solid #888888 1px;
left: 300px;
width: 380px;
display: none;
float: left;
color: #444444;
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: try to add position:relative

Comment: You need to absolutely position the dropdown and relatively position it's parent

Comment: I'm with 3rror404. `position: absolute` takes the element out of flow of document, so it wont affect other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add position relative to its parent and position absolute to itself. by doing that it will come in to layering of layout and will not break your existing layout.

add position absolute like

```
 #notification_dropdown {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

and add position relative to its parent like

```
parent_0f_dropdown
{
position:relative;
}
```